# Remove empty lines when copy text from <p>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem in firefox. There are some lines like this:

```
<p id="rec_2" class="logMess errorMess">test</p>
<p id="rec_3" class="logMess errorMess">test</p>
<p id="rec_4" class="logMess errorMess">test</p>
```

CSS:

```
    .logMess {
        color:#000;
        padding: 4px 2px 2px 3px;
        min-width: 100%;
        line-height: 18px !important;
    }
    .errorMess {
        color:#fff !important;
        background:rgb(163,0,0) !important;
    }
```

And later when I'm trying to copy text I'm receiving:

```
test

test

test
```

But I want something like this and I have no oportunity to use any framework or something like this:

```
test
test
test
```

Thanks.

Comment: what css styling do you have on your `p` elements?

Comment: So you're wanting to paste text into something like Word or what? If that's the case, then I'd say the only way around that would be to put all of those lines in one `p` element and using break tags (`<br>`) to denote a line break.

Comment: ps: added style to the question

Comment: a hint is that padding and line-height make text with more space( height)

Comment: yep, I know. But I need that line-height too

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in copy event with webkit and others. It is *NOT* about **CSS**.

Try to catch copy-event and format it.

```
document.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
  const toCopy = document.getSelection().toString();  
  console.log(toCopy);
  let toPaste = "";
  $(toCopy.split('\n')).each(function(i,v){
    if (v.length > 0) {
      if (toPaste != "") {
        toPaste += '\n';
      }
      toPaste += v;
    }
  });
  event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', toPaste);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

https://codepen.io/mike-polo/pen/WNbNGvR

Answer (score -1):

In your **CSS** file add the rules `margin:0` and `padding:0` for your `p` elements.
That will get rid of this problem.

I have created a jsFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/6490/

Comment: thnx @RustyTheBoyRobot for make my working answer's lagnuage better,hence you votedown this